# how to store image in a file cache and load it for later use in program

Tags: java, android

I want to load the images from the url while the program starts and save it in a file ....

then i  have to access the file and retrieve the images from the file ...

the loading of images should not create time delay .....

Comment: look at this Question https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

Comment: friend it uses the array String .....load images while accessing pages  i want to store it and access later my friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open source lazy image loader for android. With this loader you can download and save the images and use it later on if you already downloaded it.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview) is the Link for this StackOverFlow Question... Hope it helps !